# Angularjs: greater than filter with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm applying a greater than filter to a ng-repeat tag. I wrote the following custom filter function:

```
$scope.priceRangeFilter = function (location) {
    return location.price >= $scope.minPrice;
};
```

and I use it in the following HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in map.markers | filter:priceRangeFilter">
```

What is the best way to trigger a refresh of the ng-repeat tag when $scope.minPrice is updated?

Comment: It does refresh automatically as stated by Sza, I made a mistake in minPrice binding in the form. My apologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be automatic. When `$scope.minPrice` is changed, the repeater will be automatically updated.

```
function Ctrl($scope,  $timeout) {
    $scope.map = [{
        name: 'map1',
        price: 1
    }, {
        name: 'map2',
        price: 2
    }, {
        name: 'map3',
        price: 3
    }];
    $scope.minPrice = 0;
    $scope.priceRangeFilter = function (location) {
        return location.price >= $scope.minPrice;
    };

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.minPrice = 1.5;
    }, 2000);
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYtNL/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Create the filter as a filter service using the angularjs filter api, and add minPrice as a parameter.

```js
filter('priceRangeFilter', function ( location ) {
    return function ( location, minPrice ) {
        ...
    }
})
```

and in the template

```html
<div ng-repeat="m in map.markers | priceRangeFilter:minPrice">
```

See an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/BNNSp/1/

Comment: I would only create a registered filter only if it's actually reusable or I'm doing filtering of the same type of entity in multiple scopes that can't share the filter function

Comment: You can pass a needle to the object property you're comparing to, and you have a reusable GT filter for Array of Objects. This way your controller will be lighter. But you are right too.