# Add fiter dynamically to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want add the filters to the ng-repeat depending on there checkbox state.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: filters">
    {{user.name}} {{user.job}} {{user.min}}-{{user.max}}
</li>
```

Can filters be an array?

The second Questions is, how can i show all records, when $scope.min and $scope.max are empty (at init)?

http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/H5GMD/3/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change filters dynamically quite easily, just assign a scope variable and you can modify it.

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Au8KFg?p=preview

If you have

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: filters">
```

then your $scope variable is

```
$scope.filters = {minMax: false, ... };
```

As for the checkboxes, if your

```
<input ng-model="minMaxFilter" type="checkbox" ng-change="filters['minMax] =! filters[minMax]"/>MinMAX
```

if you want to just change the state of a filter

or if you want to add a new filter, you can attach a function with ng-click or just push a new value

```
<input ng-model="newFilterToAdd" type='text' > <button ng-click="filters.push(newFilterToAdd);">Add Filter</button>
```

to show all records, you need to not apply the filter (such as making it empty) or assigning a null to it

Comment: thank you! i will test it! do you have a solution für the min / may empty problem, when the inputs are empty no results will be shown

Comment: Sure, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972775/angularjs-greater-than-filter-with-ng-repeat this is an example of a range filter

Comment: cant get it work :( can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/H5GMD/8/ would be nice if a can add the filter dynamically. for example, i decide to do a text search in user, and after that i do a text search in job. is there a way or tutorial how i can do this? hope you understand me :(

Comment: i will add the filters in that way: http://jsfiddle.net/fdDph/9/. So I don't which filter is added by the user. will he search the name or the jobs or will he add a range filter

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding two filters for your requirement.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchText | minMax : filterParams">
            {{user.name}} {{user.job}} {{user.min}}-{{user.max}}
</li>
```

Here is working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/7TDnA/)**.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: No :( Wait I make an example...nice to see you again here :-D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/6PYNn/ her is my example...the two filter input field should generate dynamically over filterTemplate...but the first problem is to get the filter work after adding them.

Comment: You mean to say you need to add filter to ng-repeat. But the functional has to be changing according to the selection of the user?

Comment: What is template for the filter? I am not able to understand.

Comment: in my fiddle there are two input files for searchText and searchText2...at the moment they are static, but they should be dynmamic according to the users choice. sorry, my englisch isn't the best ;-)

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand.

Comment: no problem. can you help me to get the filter work? how i pass the selected filter (from add form) to the selectedFilter scope? result should be $scope.selectedFilters = {name: textFilter1, all: textFilter2 ...};

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nofear87/6PYNn/ how can i generate the return object in selectedFilters dynamically?

Comment: I guess keys of an object cannot be a dynamic value. You have to start looking for some other options of solving this problem.

Comment: what could be a solution? i haven't any idea :(

Comment: You can have multiple filters attached to ng-repeat and by making the filter object empty you can disable the filter. Plunker you have showed have made things complex. You can directly give reference as foo.name to ng-model.

Comment: but when i dynamically create <div mini-directive type="xxx" value="xxx"></div>, then my object grows? and the values are dynamic? or i'am wrong?

Comment: No your object will not grow.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EBhdblMnPvXN3GjbHSPf. when i can add more directives to the dom the object grows and the value is dynamic according to the input-field?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/egUDf2fuRMJTqRn1YMo2?p=preview. Please have a look into the last input element.

Comment: ahh ok :-) is it possible to pass foo as a filter in my fiddle?

Comment: yes you can send an object as an expression to the filter