# How can I limit rows showing in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
    <div>{{ subject.name }}</div>
 </div>
```

Is there some way that I can limit the display of rows to rows where subject.id is less than 50 if roleId > 1 and otherwise show all rows?

$scope.roleId = 0 means no filter
$scope.roleId > 0 means filter to show only rows in $scope.subjects where subject.id is less than 50

Comment: Yes, use and angular filter

Comment: Not 100% clear what expected results would be... just remove items that don't meet those criteria?

Comment: yes - remove all items with a subject.id less than 50 if the roleId which is a scope variable is greater than 1.

Comment: Is roleId a property of subject or is it a global property?

Comment: roleId = 0 means no filter
roleId > 0 means filter to show only rows with a subject.id of less than 50

roleId is a simple $scope variable

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using `ng-if` or use a filter

```
 <div ng-repeat="subject in subjects" ng-if="subject.id>50">
```

The part about the role id in question is not clear

Comment: roleId is a scope variable

Comment: Ok..so easy enough to add that into conditional

Comment: This is probably the best way, least amount of code. +1

Comment: roleId = 0 means no filter
roleId > 0 means filter to show only rows with a subject.id of less than 50

Comment: try `ng-if="!roleId || subject.id>50"`

Comment: Why subject.id > 50 when my question says "subject.id is less than 50" ?

Comment: sorry if I misread it ... surely you can make that adjustment

Comment: Thank you.  Can you tell me is ng-if better than using an inline filter if there is such a thing. What is the difference?

Comment: An array filter works by returning a new array to the view that is filtered based on conditions .... ng-if works by checking if a specific DOM element should be generated based on condidtions of the model item. With a lot of items in array....filter would be more efficient regarding adding watches

Comment: Could this be done with an inline filter if there is such a thing and if so how could that be coded?

Comment: filter needs to point to javascript function ... either in controller or as a registered angular filter. Read the docs regarding filters

Answer (score 2):

## Use Limit to Filter

```
<div ng-repeat="subject in subjects | limitTo:quantity">
    <div>{{ subject.name }}</div>
</div>
```

then set the $scope.quantity in your controller based on your business logic.

## Use a Custom Filter

to use a custom filter you just set a new `$scope` function in your controller.

```
$scope.yourFilter = function (items) {
    // probably need some more logic but you get the idea
    return items.id < 50;
};
```

thin in the filter it should look like this

```
<div ng-repeat="subject in subjects | filter:yourFilter(subjects)">
    <div>{{ subject.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do limitTo and quantity come from.  The variable I am referencing is a scope variable called roleId. I may have 1,2,5 or 99 subjects for example but if roleId is > 0 I only want to show those subjects with subjectId less than 50.

Comment: @Marilou limitTo is an angular filter. write the logic in your controller. if you only want to show specific id's then make a custom filter like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972775/angularjs-greater-than-filter-with-ng-repeat) does.

Comment: @Marilou check out the update with the custom filter.

Comment: Sorry Joe but I would like the subjects to be limited to 50 only if the $scope.roleId is > 0    If $scope.roleId = 0 I don't want any filtering

Comment: Would it not be possible to have an inline filter for this?

Comment: yeah just add the entire set of logic into the custom filter. do all your checks on it and return the item. then just add it in your html. so you need some if statement in the filter that returns the items you want, shouldn't be to hard to write.

Comment: can you add the example of an inline filter to your answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter

```
<div ng-repeat="subject in subjects | filter:filterFn">
    <div>{{ subject.name }}</div>
</div>
```

And in your controller, have this function:

```
$scope.filterFn = function (item) {
    if ($scope.roleId > 1) {
        return (item.Id < 50) ? true : false;
    }
    else
        return true;
};
```

If I understood your comments correctly.